# Convert a column value like "June 11, 2020" into an actual date so I can filter on it relative to TODAY

Tags: date

I want a column to list the upcoming dates for a meeting that I am manually entering into the drop down list. However, I want one of my views to only show the meetings that have passed. I tried to filter on column value < TODAY but the column value (is a string that happens to be a date) is defined as a multiple choice list so I can define which days the meeting occurs. Is there a way to either convert a value like "June 11, 2020" to an actual date value so I can compare it to TODAY? Or is there a way to have a date pull the options from a defined list?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I was able to use the DATEVALUE function to convert the text string to a date where I then can compare it to values like [TODAY]